# What happens to light (waves) when it falls into a room?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, scattering

For my project that includes to design an ideal window for studios and housing i need to know the science behind what happens to light that falls into a room. I know that the light rays, to some extent, get reflected and refracted by the window but what happens next? How is a room fully illuminated through daylighting.

Comment: Might be worth your while to spend some time simulating it with [3-D modelling software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_3D_modeling_software), and [ray-tracing software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ray_tracing_software) tools. Basically, tools that let you construct a virtual space, containing virtual objects, and virtual light sources...

Comment: thanks for your advice Solomon Slow. I tried out different 3d softwares but its a bit tricky as i want to explore it more as diagrams or small schemes. do you have an advice on that ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [diffuse reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_reflection)?

Comment: Yes, I have a general understanding of this concept.

Comment: Some things to consider: 1) a diffuse window (can't see thru it) will send the window light all around the room, room is brighter 2) argon gas (single atom) in a layer will help keep the IR (heat) in the room 3) coatings can reduce the normal 7% reflection lost, other coatings can reflect away excessive light 4) maybe can generate electricity(?) 5) strength/type of glass for a hurricane 6) color reflected to make the building attractive 7) UV protection ......

Answer (score 1):

Light will enter the room through the windows (without much loss) and then bounce (be reflected) off the walls and furniture.

The amount of light reflected is given by the LRV (Light Reflectance Value). LRV is measured from 100 (100% white reflecting everything) to 0 (100% black absorbing everything). White wall paint seems to have an LRV of about 65-70 meaning it reflects about $\frac 2 3$ of the light falling on it after the first reflection. Darker colours are less. If the finish is matt it will be reflected in all directions, more-or-less. A gloss surface will reflect more of the light in a single direction (like a mirror). If that light falls on another wall it will be reflected again, so potentially $\frac 4 9$ of the light can be reflected off the second surface. Eventually, after enough reflections, all of the light will be absorbed.

So you can see that the surface directly facing the window will receive the most light but other surfaces (as long as they are not completely obscured) will still get a significant amount of light.